# Node.js Express: Ajax call from ejs to app.js fetching data render div dynamically

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, ejs

I have an express app with node.js that,

1) `app.get('/', routes.index)` points to my index.ejs.

2) there is a button on my index.ejs. When it is clicked, I want to call the dataGrab function in app.js to retrieve the data remotely and display in index.ejs as a `<table>` dynamically.

in my app.js

```
var data=[];
grab = function() {
   .... grab data remotely and push to data[]
}
```

As the button actually sits on the client side, if I want to call grab() in app.js to populate the data[] and use it to render a table on index.ejs, is using ajax the only way? If yes, could u share a simple code sample?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Yes, AJAX is the only way (without refreshing) - just make a call to your route via JS

Comment: there is still an issue here that after i do this ajax call, browser will navigate to localhost:3000/grab. If I click back btn to localhost:3000. The results are correctly appended it to the table element. May I know how to stop this unexpected navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for tymeJV, it sends up I am using the code below ,

***** edit to add ajax call

inside of my ejs I am using

```
<script>
$.get('/grab',function(data) {
        for(var h=0; h<data.length;h++){
    $('#newsItemTable').append('<tr><td>'+data[h].name+'</td></tr>');
        }
     });
</script>
```

while in my app.js I m using

```
app.get('/grab', function(req, res) {

....
res.send(data);

}
```

Comment: there is still an issue here that after i do this ajax call, browser will navigate to localhost:3000/grab. If I click back btn to localhost:3000. The results are correctly appended it to the table element. May I know how to stop this unexpected navigation?